# User defined object as function specified parameter type in Python

Tags: python, function, class, oop, parameter-passing

I defined my class Player in Python3 and now I am trying to define a method in another class that would take an object type Player as a parameter, so a code would look like that:

```
def change_player_activity(self, player: Player):
    pass
```

But that gives me an error. I know that I could do a following operation:

```
if not isinstance(player,Player):
        raise TypeError
```

But I am just wondering, is there any built-in way to tell Python3 to accept only the objects of given class?

Comment: "But that gives me an error." What kind of error?

Comment: No. Python is not C or Java or any other statically-typed language. Type hinting are just, well, hints. You can check for the type with `isinstance` or if you really want to have a go with at it, with metaclasses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any built-in way to tell Python3 to accept on the objects of a given class?

No.

This doesn't exist, and wouldn't be useful anyway because Python relies on the principle of Duck Typing. If it looks like a `Player`, and quacks like a `Player`, treat it as a player. Otherwise, `raise TypeError`.

You should only be raising `TypeError` when you ask the object to do something that a `Player` should be able to do, and it can't do that. What if somebody wants to pass an instance of their own `Player` class into your function? It won't work then.

---

Back to your actual problem: You want to type-hint `Player` before `Player` is defined. The way to do this is to [write `"Player"` instead of `Player`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) in the type hint:

```
def change_player_activity(self, player: "Player"):
    pass
```

In `__future__` (pun intended), the Python developers plan to make it [not try to look up type hints straight away](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) because this sort of thing is a pain.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "own `Player` class", that's already handled. An instance of a subclass of `Player` is still, in every meaningful sense, an instance of `Player` as well.

Comment: @chepner I mean one that isn't a subclass; there are reasons to do this, such as to avoid metaclass hideousness.

Comment: There would be equally valid reasons to believe that such a class doesn't quack enough like a "real" `Player` to be considered a valid substitute.

Comment: @chepner In which case some call or other will fail. Then you can raise a `TypeError`. Having a slow check for `isinstance` every call is not very efficient.

Comment: I think we agree. If `isinstance` is used, it should be done to affect how the function handles the argument, not simply to decide whether or not to raise a `TypeError` (or some other exception). I'm of the opinion that in a dynamically typed language, it's the caller's responsibility to pass values of the correct type, rather than the callee's responsibility to reject values of the wrong type. Type hints are a tool to help in the latter case.